# Що таке "сплавиноченьки"?

Tags: значення-слів

У К. Сосенка (Сосенко, Ксенофонт Петрович. Культурно-історична постать староукраїнських свят Різдва і Щедрого Вечера / Ксенофонт Сосенко. – Львів: Накладом авт., 1928. – IX, 349 c.) сьогодні натрапила на цікавий текст:

> ой течут, течут, бистрі річеньки
>
> на тих річеньках **сплавиноченьки**
>
> на тих **сплавононьках** по три вершечки...

Цікавить, що означає слово "сплавиноченьки"? Щось не можу дати собі ради у тлумаченні. З контексту мені нічого на гадку не спадає, бо весь текст надто короткий. Проте мені відомо, що це колядка.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Даний уривок поданий з [комогонічної колядки](http://spadok.org.ua/zymovi-zvychayi-ta-obryady/schedruy-i-velychaysya-ukrayino-oberegy-ukrayinskoyi-tradytsiyi-kolyadky-i-schedrivky).
 У статті Станіслава Губерначука  [ДАЖБОГ МЕНЕ ВИСЛАВ](http://www.redkyb.ru/svarohs/sv11_12/vyslav.htm)  знаходимо:

> Плине, сплавиноченьки — з того кореня, що й наші слова, народ утворив назву міста Плав, що згадується в “Літопису руському”. Своє українське слово плави використав перекладач “Остромирового євангелія”: “І видіте ниви яко плав”.

Очевидно, йде мова про [СПЛАВ](http://sum.in.ua/s/splav) :

> Пліт із сплавного лісу. Лісові підприємці.. почали висилати [Вовкуна] зі сплавами до Журавна, ба й до Окопів, повіряючи йому продаж дерева (Іван Франко, III, 1950, 48); — А що вже сплави збивати та гонити, то рівні йому в цій роботі поміж нас не було (Ігор Муратов, Буковинська повість, 1959, 16)

Або про [ПЛАВ](http://sum.in.ua/s/plav)

> 3. Сміття, різні предмети, що пливуть по річці суцільним потоком (звичайно під час повені). Я пливу за водою.. І плав пливе. Пропливають лози, верби, в'язи, тополі у воді (Олександр Довженко, Зачарована Десна, 1957, 476);  * У порівняннях. Злилось як плав (Словник Грінченка).
> 4. Невеликі мулувато-торф'янисті плавучі утворення з коренів і стебел очерету, рогозу, вкриті рослинами. Кругом обняла його [хутір] річка з зеленими плавами, лозами й очеретами (Пантелеймон Куліш, Вибр., 1969, 49); Плави постійно або періодично плавають, вони відокремлені від берегів або з'єднані з ними (Ботанічний журнал, X, 3, 1953, 34).
> 5. Ділянка трясовини, де під шаром рослинності є вода. Вночі через болото переходила [Оленка], в плаву провалилася (Костянтин Гордієнко, Діти.., 1937, 44).

Отже, сплавиноченьки -це пестлива форма слів **"ПЛАВ"**, або **"Сплав"**

Answer (score 2):

**Сплав** + **-ин·а-** + [**-ечк-** чи **-оньк-**](https://r2u.org.ua/guides/synyavsky/slovotvir_narostky)

[Велика совітська енциклопедія](http://vre.pp.ua/vre_splavina.html)

> **Сплавини**, зибун, плаваючий на поверхні водойми килим водних і болотних рослин. У водоймах, багатих поживними речовинами, С. складається з очерету, рогозу, вахти та ін кореневищних рослин і зелених мохів; в бідних поживними речовинами - в основному з сфагнових мохів (див. Сфагнум ). Наростає С. від берегів до центру, покриваючи іноді весь водойму. При створенні водосховищ особливо небезпечні надиловие С. (тобто підстилаються мулом), які після затоплення перетворюються у вільно плаваючі острови, що перешкоджають судноплавству і що утрудняють роботу ГЕС.

Инше: [Горох](https://goroh.pp.ua/%D0%A2%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F/%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0) (не знаю на якому джерелі базується, ймовірно народний)

> **Сплавина** Шар водних і болотяних рослин, що наповзають з берега на поверхню водоймища.

Також [можливо](https://uk.wikisource.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0:%D0%95%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D1%96%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B7%D0%B1%D1%96%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA_%D0%A2.35.djvu/150) (тут чомусь *сплаво<del>но</del>ньках*, можливий одрук) і просто [згаданий](/a/3633/585) *сплав* пані Іванки Сеновʼят.